# Date range in specific format in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have to put start_date and end_date in python.
My requirement is I want date_range in the below mention format.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a = 'yesterday' # I don't want to hardcore the date value
b = '7daysAgo'
start_date = a 00:00:00
end_date = b 23:59:59
```

the hour min & second in should be same, it will not be impacted whenever time I used the code.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question im not sure if you want a date object with that format or a string formatted like in the question:
Formatted string:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

end_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
end_date = end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

Date Object

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = yesterday.replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=00,microsecond=00)

end_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
end_date = end_date.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59,microsecond=00)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html